# create class instances from json array

Tags: ios, json, swift

I load a json array with this format

```
[{
    id = 1;
    name = “test1”;
}, {
    id = 2;
    name = “test2”;
}, {
    id = 3;
    name = “test#”;
}, {
    id = 4;
    name = “test$”;
}]
```

And I have a class called `MyClass(id: int, name: String)`. For each element in the json I want to create an instance of MyClass. objects containt an array of the json element. Would it be possible to do something like

```
for object in objects{
MyClass(object)
}
```

or how shall I parse the json?

Comment: That is *not JSON.* It looks like the description of an `(NS)Array`

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thats the JSON parsed to NSArray

Comment: So you already have parsed the array and can iterate over it. What is your question?

Comment: How to create an instance of MyClass from the objects contained in the array

Comment: @user567 Before posting such a novice question, first please learn swift a little bit. [A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1) might be very helpful.

And answer to you question, please take a look on the link [MyClass Initialization Example](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59a04ce4f2733d2f5ebc6359)

Comment: @MehediHasan Please read at least the question before commenting. This is exactly what I don't want to do. What if my json hat 30 attributes? The solution I was looking for is is to use self.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(JSONDictionary) at the initializer.